# How apply gradient boosting to this function and this data?

Tags: python, numpy, gradient, gradient-descent

```
def square_A(B_estimated, x, y):
    B_estimated = np.matrix(B_estimated)
    z = y - np.dot(x, B_estimated.T)
    return np.dot(z.T, z)
# Where x and y is defined here:
m = 1000
n = 100

x0 = np.ones([m, 1]) 
x1 = np.random.uniform(0, 10, ([m, n]))
x = np.concatenate([x0, x1], axis = 1)

beta = np.random.randint(-5, 5, size = ([1, n + 1]))
error = np.random.normal(0, 1, (m, 1))

y = np.dot(x, beta.T) + error
```

The variable that i want to minimize is "B_estimated".
If you need more information about the prblem ask me.